# GCM Notifications are ignored on the device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to do some GCM notifications on Android. I've come as far as having something happen on the device.

NotificationService is throwing the following exception:

```
12-11 16:02:19.650      202-380/? E/NotificationService﹕ Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(contentView=org.***.**.reciever/0x1090098 vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0)
```

Here is my manifest for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.***.**.reciever"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission android:name="org.***.**.reciever.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="org.***.**.reciever.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/***"
    android:name=".***Application" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="org.***.**.reciever.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="util.GcmBroadcastReciever"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="org.***.**.reciever" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="util.GcmIntentService" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="***"/>
</application>
```

All the ***.** are just the masked package name, they are all the same.

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Also, is the notification supposed to pop up on the device without any extra code or does the app have to ask the OS to show a notification on the screen when the GCM push arrives? I think i read something about Android doing this part differently from iOS.

Comment: are you trying to show a notification when the push comes in? when a push comes in a notification does not automatically show, you have to create one

Comment: Ok, Ill investigate that. However the error message Im getting leads me to believe that i have to fix that before i can show the notification?

Comment: that does not look related to GCM, but rather to the way you pass notifications to the notification manager. you need to post your code for showing a notification.

Comment: Please post your GcmBroadcastReciever and GcmIntentService code.

Comment: I dont know, you posted no code for me to tell you what is wrong, it looks like you are trying to show an empty notification where nothing is set

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it's not the actual push message that's causing the issue as i thought. So i was barking up the wrong tree for a couple hours.

It turns out it was the actual notification that had an issue because it was demo code from Google >.<

Replaced with proper code -> working.

Thanks for your time!